# Too many DML Statements: 1 In LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

I've been trying to research on how to solve this issue but it doesn't seem like I've been having much luck. I've cut out all of the additional functionality so that it only remains with a single upsert

Here's my apex function

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void savePositions(List<CFIM__Position__c> positions, Id siteId) {
     upsert positions;
}
```

I tried running this function by itself in the developer console and it works fine. Here's my LWC function

```
import savePositions from '@salesforce/apex/lwc_SitePositions.savePositions';

...
    saveDataTable() {
        savePositions({positions: this.positionRecords, siteId: this.recordId})
            .then(response => console.log(response));
    }
```

Comment: I would associate this issue with your method being annotated as `cacheable=true` though your question does not show this. Are you sure the `@AuraEnabled` annotation is not parameterized?

Comment: maybe there are triggers running that are causing this error? If you capture a debug log, you should be able to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, so the issue I was having was that upsert wasn't working, but was fine when I seperated insert and update depending on when Id was located. I also was passing 'id' instead of 'Id', and fixing these two issues